# Counting line occurrence and dividing by total number of lines - unix / python

Tags: python, unix, count, text-files, uniq

I have a textfile `test.in` as such:

```
english<tab>walawala
foo bar<tab>laa war
foo bar<tab>laa war
hello world<tab>walo lorl
hello world<tab>walo lorl
foo bar<tab>laa war
```

The desired output should be:

```
english<tab>walawala<tab>0.1666
foo bar<tab>laa war<tab>0.5
hello world<tab>walo lorl<tab>0.3333
```

The new column is the count of the line divided by the total number of lines.

Currently i'm doing this:

```
cat test.in | uniq -c | awk '{print $2"\t"$3"\t"$1}' > test.out
```

But that only gives me the count of the lines not the probability. Also, my file is really huge, like 1,000,000,000 lines with at least 20 chars per column.

**How could I get the desired output correctly and quickly?**

**Is there a pythonic solution that is as fast?**

Comment: Did you try `wc`? 

``q=`cat test.in | wc -l`;cat test.in | uniq -c | awk '{print $2"\t"$3"\t"$1'/$q'}'``

Comment: @user189 [useless use of cat](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) alert. :)

Comment: Note that the floating point is rounded...

Answer (score 7):

Note that the uniq only counts repeated lines, and it must be preceded by sort for it to consider all lines in a file. For `sort | uniq -c`, the following code using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is much more effective as it does not need to sort anything at all:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('test.in') as inf:
    counts = sorted(Counter(line.strip('\r\n') for line in inf).items())
    total_lines = float(sum(i[1] for i in counts))
    for line, freq in counts:
         print("{}\t{:.4f}".format(line, freq / total_lines))
```

This script outputs

```
english<tab>walawala<tab>0.1667
foo bar<tab>laa war<tab>0.5000
hello world<tab>walo lorl<tab>0.3333
```

for the input given in your description.

---

However if you need to coalesce only successive lines, like **`uniq -c`**, note that any solution using `Counter` gives the output given in your question, but your `uniq -c` approach will **not**. The output of `uniq -c will be`:

```
  1 english<tab>walawala
  2 foo bar<tab>laa war
  2 hello world<tab>walo lorl
  1 foo bar<tab>laa war
```

**not**

```
  1 english<tab>walawala
  3 foo bar<tab>laa war
  2 hello world<tab>walo lorl
```

If this is the behavior you *want*, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('foo.txt') as inf:
    grouper = groupby(line.strip('\r\n') for line in inf)
    items = [ (k, sum(1 for j in i)) for (k, i) in grouper ]
    total_lines = float(sum(i[1] for i in items))
    for line, freq in items:
        print("{}\t{:.4f}".format(line, freq / total_lines))
```

The difference is that given a `test.in` having the contents as you prescribe, the uniq pipe would *not* produce the output you gave in the example, instead you would get:

```
english<tab>walawala<tab>0.1667
foo bar<tab>laa war<tab>0.3333
hello world<tab>walo lorl<tab>0.3333
foo bar<tab>laa war<tab>0.1667
```

As this is not what your input example said, it can be that you can't use `uniq` without `sort` to solve your problem - then you need to resort to my first example and Python will be most certainly faster than your Unix command line.

---

By the way, these work identically in all Pythons > 2.6.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pure AWK solution:

```
<test.in awk '{a[$0]++} END {for (i in a) {print i, "\t", a[i]/NR}}'
```

It uses AWK's arrays and the special variable `NR`, which keeps track of the number of lines.

Let's dissect the code.  The first block

```
{a[$0]++}
```

is executed *once for each line* in the input.  Here `$0` represents every single line, and it is used as an index over the array `a`, which therefore just *counts the number of occurrences of each line*.

The second block

```
END {for (i in a) {print i, "\t", a[i]/NR}}
```

is executed *at the end* of the input.  At this point, `a` contains the number of occurrences for each line in the input and is indexed by the lines themselves: hence by cycling over it we are able to print a table of lines and relative occurrences (we divide by the total number of lines, `NR`).

Answer (score 2):

```python
from collections import Counter

with open('data.txt') as infile:
    # Counter will treat infile as an iterator and exhaust it
    counter = Counter(infile)

    # Don't know if you need sorting but this will sort in descending order
    counts = ((line.strip(), n) for line, n in counter.most_common())

    # Convert to proportional amounts
    total = sum(counter.values())
    probs = [(line, n / total) for line, n in counts]

    print("\n".join("{}{}".format(*p) for p in probs))
```

This has several advantages. It iterates through the lines in the file rather than loading the whole file, it takes advantage of existing `Counter` functionality, it can sort, and it's clear what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

A solution in Python, but I'm not sure about performance on 1,000,000,000 lines.

```
d = {}
s = "english<tab>walawala\nfoo bar<tab>laa war\nfoo bar<tab>laa war\nhello world<tab>walo lorl\nhello world<tab>walo lorl\nfoo bar<tab>laa war"
c = 0

for l in s.split("\n"):
  c += 1
  if d.has_key(l):
    d[l] += 1
  else:
    d[l] = 1

for k,v in d.items():
  print k + " -> " + str(float(v)/float(c))
```

Output :

```
english<tab>walawala -> 0.166666666667
foo bar<tab>laa war -> 0.5
hello world<tab>walo lorl -> 0.333333333333
```

Edit : this solution can be improved using the Counter object in Python : https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Maybe you could use Counter?

Comment: Yup didn't know about that tool. You can adapt my solution using this : https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: RAM is cheap nowadays :D

Comment: @Jerk31 1 billion lines * 20 characters = 20 billion bytes = 20GB of ram. Probably excessive.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by using dictionaries in python that automatically can only have one value

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict_counter = defaultdict(float)
counter = 0

for line in open('test.in'):
    my_dict_counter[line] += 1
    counter += 1 

for line in my_dict_counter:
    print line.strip() + "\t" + str(my_dict_counter[line]/counter)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution in Python:

```
my_dict = {}
counter = 0 
with open('test.in') as f:
    for line in f:
        counter += 1
        try:
            my_dict[line] = (my_dict[line]+1)
        except:
            my_dict[line] = 1

for line in my_dict:
    print("%s%s%.4f" % (line[:-1], "<tab>", my_dict[line]/float(counter)))
```

Output:

```
english<tab>walawala<tab>0.1667
hello world<tab>walo lorl<tab>0.3333
foo bar<tab>laa war<tab>0.5000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
with open("test.in") as f:
    counts = Counter(f)
total = sum(counts.values())
for k, v in counts.items():
    print("{0}<tab>{1:0.4f}".format(k.strip(), v / total))
```

This does not sort on probability. The performance is O(3n) because of the three loops and this could be reduced to O(2n) by using a subclass of TexIOBase which keeps track of lines or a subclass of Counter that keeps track of total lines processed.

Answer (score 1):

If it's too expensive to do all the processing in RAM, you could consider a simple database. sqlite comes with all installations of python. This example could easily be optimized, but I felt simplicity favored speed when demonstrating the approach:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('counts.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE counts (phrase TEXT PRIMARY KEY, num INT)')
conn.commit()

recs = 0
with open('test.in') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        recs += 1

        # see if already exists
        c.execute("SELECT count(1) FROM counts WHERE phrase=?", (line,))
        count = int(c.fetchone()[0]) + 1
        if count == 1:
            # add new record
            c.execute("INSERT INTO counts VALUES(?,1)", (line,))
        else:
            # update record
            c.execute("UPDATE counts SET num=?", (count,))

        if recs % 10000 == 0:
            conn.commit()

conn.commit()

for row in c.execute("SELECT phrase,num FROM counts ORDER BY phrase"):
    print "%s\t%f" % (row[0], float(row[1]) / recs)
```